Can my automated jobs append to the remote branch without fetching the latest tip?
I have four jobs (via GitHub actions) that run in parallel and commit to the repository. This creates a race condition where if one job finishes pushing first, the others fail with:
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/amingilani/canada-amateur-radio-test-bank-archive'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. If you want to integrate the remote changes,
hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Unfortunately, git pull doesn't solve this because it's possible that after fetching the current tip in job A, another job might push a commit before job A can commit and push. This will result in the same error.
Is there a way to append my commit based on an outdated parent ref to the tip of the remote branch without:

Fetching the current tip first, or
Overwriting the branch

Potential solution for non-GitHub.com remotes
Use a server-side hook to process the commit. If it's a commit with an outdated ref, update the ref.
Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my scenario since I'm on GitHub.com.

I would use a different technology for your archival system.  git is not designed for blind automatic commits like this, especially by multiple tools.  It's designed so that multiple actors coordinate by merging.  I would try a generic object store like S3 or Azure Blob Storage.  Both have simple APIs.

Can you give an outline of what the 4 jobs do ?

@LeGEC it's a poor man's archival service. Once a day, each job checks to see if a remote file has been updated. If so, it's archived in the repository.

ok, would grouping the 4 actions in one single sequential script work, then ?

@LeGEC correct :) That is the solution I went with after posting this. Please feel free to write this and I'll accept yours as the best answer.

Maybe you could use pull-requests. In each job, update the local branch, commit the changes, push to a temporary branch, call API to create a PR from this temporary branch to the target branch, call API to accept the PR and delete the temporary branch. Accepting the PR may fail due to merge conflicts.

@ElpieKay actually, this might merge. I've seen GitHub actions that update your PR after an update in the main branch. This would keep the PRs up-to-date. I'll try this out when I have a little more time.

Since GitHub.com doesn't offer server side hooks, and git push does not allow amending. The best solution I have at this time is to run each job sequentially.
I achieved this in GitHub actions by specifying a needs parameter for 3/4 jobs, each pointing to the job above it in the file.
This makes the total run time of the actions longer, but it side-steps the issue outlined in the question. Each job fetch a fresh copy of the repository, and each job waits for the preceding job to finish. This ensures there is no race condition.
